# How to overlay multiple video on image using Ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android

I want overlay multiple videos on the image and create new video, and remove all audio of the video.

```
String[] cmd={"-i","/storage/emulated/0/Download/videocollage.png","-i",videopaththree,"-i",videopathone,"-i",videopathone,"-i",videopathone,"-filter_complex","[1:v]scale=1029:838[tfg];[2:v]scale=990:1200[bfg];[3:v]scale=510:877[threefg];[4:v]scale=500:877[fourfg];[0:v][tfg]overlay=0:86[ol];[ol][bfg]overlay=main_w-overlay_w:538[oll];[oll][threefg]overlay=0:934[olll];[olll][fourfg]overlay=546:934","out.mp4"};
```

the above command creates a video with a background image, and multiple videos but only first video audio play another video play without audio. It takes a long time to execute.

I want to create a new video without any audio and reduce execution time.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all audio, use the switch `-an`.

From the `ffmpeg` documentation:

> -an (output)
>   Disable audio recording. For full manual control see the -map option.

Here is the link: [ffmpeg audio options](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Audio-Options)